# Trying to enumerate array and select objects based on comparison to user defaults value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I have an array of dictionaries, which represent flashcards. One of the key-value pairs is `pgFinishedNumber` and the page on which the flashcard appears in a workbook. Users also set a value in the app, `pagesDone`, to track their progress through the workbook.

I am using a Block to go through the master flashcard array and add cards to another array, called `myDailyArray`. I want flashcards whose page number is greater than the value of `pagesDone` to be moved, but I have two problems.

The first problem occurs when more than one flashcard has the same page number. When this happens, only the first card is included in  `myDailyArray`. The second problem occurs when the user indicates that he is on a page number for which there is no new flashcard.  When this happens, the next flashcard in the array is added ahead of time.

The code for my block, which is in `viewWillAppear:`, is as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

//......some code

[theLevelArray.level1Array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
NSMutableDictionary *dictDaily = [theLevelArray.level1Array objectAtIndex:idx];

[self.myDailyArray addObject:dictDaily];

int pgFinishedNumber = [[dictDaily objectForKey: @"pgFinishedNumber"] intValue];

if (pagesDone <= pgFinishedNumber)
    {
        *stop = YES;
    }  
}];
```

For example, page 3 of the workbook introduces two flashcards.  The `NSDictionary`s for these two cards both have `3` as the value for `pgFinishedNumber`.  When I enter `3` in the user default `pagesDone` and then run the app, only the first of those two gets added to `myDailyArray`.  When I change the `pagesDone` to `4`, not only do both flashcards with the `pgFinishedNumber` value of "3" get added to `myDailyArray`, but also the *next* object, which has a `pgFinishedNumber` value of `5`! I'm mystified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stopping the iteration when the first page number is reached that is greater than or equal to `pagesDone`. That means any following pages, which might have the same page number, will be ignored.

You should stop the iteration when `pgFinishedNumber` is greater than (but not equal to) `pagesDone` and move the if statement to the top of your block (before you add the page).

I think this should also fix your second problem, which I think results from the if statement being at the end of the block.

Something like this should work:

```
NSArray *levelArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"pgFinishedNumber", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"pgFinishedNumber", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"pgFinishedNumber", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"pgFinishedNumber", nil], nil];

NSMutableArray *myDailyArray = [NSMutableArray array];
int pagesDone = 4;
[levelArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictDaily = (NSMutableDictionary *)obj;
    int pgFinishedNumber = [[dictDaily objectForKey: @"pgFinishedNumber"] intValue];
    if (pagesDone < pgFinishedNumber) {
        *stop = YES;
    } else {
        [myDailyArray addObject:dictDaily];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", myDailyArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  I have changed the iteration to:  if (pagesDone < pgFinishedNumber).  I have also moved the entire if statement: if (pagesDone < pgFinishedNumber)
        {
            *stop = YES;
        } to the top just beneath the block declaration.  This presents the problem now that all the flashcards from the master flashcard array now are added to the myDailyArray.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you retrieving `pgFinishedNumber` _before_ the if statement? Also, when you set the `stop` flag, you must be careful not to execute the rest of the block.

Comment: I now moved NSMutableDictionary *dictDaily = [theLevelArray.level1Array objectAtIndex:idx]; to the top so I could get a value from int pgFinishedNumber = [[dictDaily objectForKey: @"pgFinishedNumber"] intValue]; which I realized is needed to access pgFinishedNumber.  Now i'm back to the original two problems. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, now I am retrieving it before the if statement.  I'm not sure how to be careful not to execute the rest of the block when I set the stop flag. Could you tell me how to do that? (I thought that's what the stop flag did.  I know I have a lot to learn.)

Comment: I've added some code to my answer. You will of course need to modify it to use your properties etc., I've just used some test data. Note the `else` block after the if statement, this ensures that when the iteration is stopped, the current element isn't added anymore. The `stop` flag will just be evaluated when the block ends (unlike a `break` statement in a regular loop). Also note that there's no need to use `objectAtIndex:` within the block, the object is provided to you as a parameter as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and let you know! Truly grateful for your help.